# Zoom to 100%-Shortcut in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I'm unable to set the **Zoom level to 100%** by using my beloved Shortcut <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**1**</kbd>
after upgrading Photoshop to its newest version (CC; 14.0; x64).

I can still use the Zoom tool (<kbd>**Z**</kbd>) and click the appearing <kbd>**100%**</kbd>, but thats not really handy.

**Is this a known (and maybe fixable) bug or indented behavour?**

Comment: CTRL/Command + 1 still zooms to 100%. Check your keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you @Scott, I didn't knew about the `Keyboard Shortcuts`-menu before. For some strange reason it was set to `1` instead of `Ctrl+1` (didn't touch any of it!).

Comment: Also check that your numlock is ON. This bit me just now, and I ended up here before realizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your keyboard shortcuts in preferences or simply press alt and use the scroll bar which is much more convinient